# Mod Rewrite Restrict Access

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using Zend Skeleten Application and having following rules in .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Tried to restrict accest only to 4 particular urls

1. `/` (index page)
2. `/login`
3. `/register`
4. `/auth` (authorrized page)

by adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !register$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !login$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !auth$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /chat/ [NC]
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

- Full path to index file `localhost/test` or `localhost/test/index`
- Full path to login file `localhost/test/login`
- Full path to register file `localhost/test/register`
- Full path to authfile `localhost/test/auth`

**Issue Problem**

localhost/test/ is same as localhost/test/index and localhost/test/index/index
save for localhost/test/login the same as localhost/test/login/index. Tried to implement this in .htaccess. But it doesn't seem to work [OR] condition.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/(register|login|index|auth)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/(register|login|index|auth)/(index)$ [OR] **edited**
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/$ 
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

**Resolved Issue**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/(\/|register|register/index|login|login/index|index|index/index|auth|auth/index|)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: You need `[OR]` flag in your `RewriteCond` they can't be true at once.

Comment: I really don't understand your edited issue, please try to breakdown the problem. And why you have same two conditions?

Comment: Forgot do add **/(index)** part for second rule. In **Resolved Issue** edite first rule and got this which works and it's fine for me. It there is a way to optimize it it woul be perfect, if not thanks for help @ Rahil Wazir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(register|login|index|auth)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: when accessing another link from project there must appeart a 403 error for all links excepts this 4. is this possible using [R=403,NC] or something like that?

Comment: @user3799263 `403 Forbidden` can be fire with `[F]` flag.

Comment: @user3799263 You need to prevent access for all links accept the above 4?

Comment: Yes only those four links to be avaible for accesing current web project and how to throw a [F] flag when trying to acces another page?.

Comment: theoretical it should work but seems Zend Framework doesn't recognize it. I deleted all from .htaccess to see if project sees file and it does.

But applying such condition doesn't change anything in it's work.

Comment: @user3799263 You should place this rule at top of other rules. Also make sure if your project is in `test` directory. Then you need this condition `!^/test/(register|login|index|auth)$`

Comment: Putted between 2 rewrite rules showed at beginning of post. Havin last issue. Look at Issue Problem at begin of post.

Comment: Sorry just now finished to add **Issue Problem** at the end of question block.